# Programar empate en Python

Tags: python

Es un problema simple quizas, pero llevo varios días intentando solucionarlo y lamentablemente no logro hacerlo.

Necesito programar un lista de ganadores en python.

Los datos que usé son:

```
jugadores = ["Gabriel","Juan","Pedro"]
puntos = [200,150,300]
```

Pude programarlo bien y la función final me devuelve un print con el puesto de cada jugador y los puntos que obtuvo. Por ejemplo,

```
Puesto 1: El Jugador Nro 3, Pedro, con 300 puntos.
Puesto 2: El Jugador Nro 1, Gabriel, con 200 puntos.
Puesto 3: El Jugador Nro 2, Juan, con 150 puntos.
```

El problema surge cuando hay un empate.

Si, por ejemplo, los datos cambiaran a:

```
jugadores = ["Gabriel","Juan","Pedro"]
puntos = [200,200,300]
```

El programa me devuelve:

```
Puesto 1: El Jugador Nro 3, Pedro, con 300 puntos.
Puesto 2: El Jugador Nro 1, Gabriel, con 200 puntos.
Puesto 3: El Jugador Nro 1, Gabriel, con 200 puntos.
```

Como pueden ver, me toma dos veces  el mismo jugador en distinto puesto e ignora al tercer jugador. Yo necesito que me devuelva los distintos jugadores en el mismo puesto.

```
Puesto 1 Pedro con 300 puntos,
Puesto 2 Gabriel y Juan con 200 puntos.
```

Otros datos que necesito obtener son:

```
ganador="nombre_ganador"
puntaje_ganador = 300
```

En el caso de que hayan dos o más ganadores por empate se deben guardar todos los nombres y puntos. (Esos datos los voy a usar mas tarde para guardar y sumar los puntos del ganador (solo el puesto nro 1) a una suerte de ranking de puntos acumulados en una base de datos).

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme!

Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: Que tal Laura, bienvenida... Puedes mostrarnos tu código? Servirá de mucho para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: Hola Laura, bienvenida a [es.so]. Te recomiendo pasarte por [tour] y [ask] para conocer por encima como funciona el sitio y cómo hacer buenas preguntas. Es imposible que podamos ayudarte a depurar tu código si solo explicas en que falla pero no muestras el propio código o al menos un [mcve].   Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

lo que puedes hacer es ayudarte con varias estructuras de datos para que te faciliten el trabajo. 
Puedes asignar a cada persona su puntuación utilizando un diccionario y sucesivamente guardar todas las puntuaciones obtenidas por los participantes en un set con las cuales vas a construir otro diccionario. En este tu value va a ser un listado de todos los participantes que obtuvieron esa puntuación que será el key del nuevo diccionario. Al final imprimes los resultados con dos for anidados y puedes utilizar una variable para que diga el lugar del participante. Dependiendo de la política de tu juego puede o no que haya brincos de lugares si muchos usuarios obtuvieron la misma puntuación. Mira este ejemplo para que puedas entender mejor.

```
resultados_parciales = dict()
resultados_finales = dict()
participantes = list()
puntuaciones = set()

resultados_parciales["Gabriel"] = 200
resultados_parciales["Juan"] = 200
resultados_parciales["Pedro"] = 300
participantes.append("Gabriel")
participantes.append("Juan")
participantes.append("Pedro")


for i in participantes:
    puntuaciones.add(resultados_parciales[i])

for i in puntuaciones:
    resultados_finales[i] = list()

for i in participantes:
    p = resultados_parciales[i]
    resultados_finales[p].append(i)

puntuaciones = list(puntuaciones)

puntuaciones.sort(reverse=True)

i = 1
for p in puntuaciones:
    for w in resultados_finales[p]:
        print(i, 'lugar:', w)
    i += 1
```

Output:

```
1 lugar: Pedro
2 lugar: Gabriel
2 lugar: Juan
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Puedes construir un diccionario en el que cada clave sea una puntuación, y cada valor una lista de los jugadores que han obtenido esa puntuación. Por ejemplo, para el primer caso de los que ejemplificas el diccionario resultante sería:

```
{150: ['Juan'], 200: ['Gabriel'], 300: ['Pedro']}
```

Para el segundo caso que pones como ejemplo el diccionario sería:

```
{200: ['Gabriel', 'Juan'], 300: ['Pedro']}
```

La siguiente función sirve para crear un diccionario así:

```
def make_ranking(jugadores, puntos):
  ranking = {}
  for jugador, pts in zip(jugadores, puntos):
      if pts not in ranking:
        ranking[pts] = []  # Creamos la lista vacía para esa puntuación
      ranking[pts].append(jugador) # Y añadimos a ella un jugador
  return ranking
```

Que usarías así:

```
jugadores = ["Gabriel","Juan","Pedro"]
puntos = [200,200,300]

ranking = make_ranking(jugadores, puntos)
```

Una vez tienes este diccionario (`ranking`), encontrar al ganador (o la lista de ganadores si hay empate) se reduce a encontrar el máximo de las claves de ese diccionario:

```
puntaje_ganador = max(ranking)
```

y los nombres de los ganadores sería el valor asociado con esa clave.

```
ganador = ranking[puntaje_ganador]
```

Para imprimir el ranking puedes hacer otra función que itere por las claves del diccionario, ordenadas de mayor a menor, y para cada una imprima adecuadamente formateada la lista de jugadores correspondientes a esa clave. Por ejemplo:

```
def print_ranking(ranking):
  for puesto, puntuacion in enumerate(sorted(ranking, reverse=True),start=1):
    print("Puesto {}: {} con {} puntos".format(
              puesto, 
              " y ".join(ranking[puntuacion]), 
              puntuacion))
```

Que usarías así:

```
print_ranking(ranking)
```

lo que mostraría en este caso:

```
Puesto 1: Pedro con 300 puntos
Puesto 2: Gabriel y Juan con 200 puntos
```